# Enable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on NGINX (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl

What is the procedure to lower security on NGINX?

I already tried this on nginx.conf:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:@SECLEVEL=1";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Also in openssl.cnf:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf


[ default_conf ]

ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]

system_default = ssl_default_sect

[ssl_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

However the changes had no effect.
[TLS Checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CskCO.png)

Comment: Tozatto did you found any solution to this? I have the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Nope, I didn't find anything that work in this case, my solution was to make an simple API and host in IIS suporting all tsl, then redirect to nginx using TLS 1.2.

Comment: Tozatto I've just  solved it by allowing all TLS versions on global level in nginx and then restricting it only on few server. In this way I was able to allow 1.1 TLS. Maybe it works also on your case.